Multipass LXC IP address issue
Environment info: I am on Ubuntu 22.04 server, running Multipass 1.14, and LXC 5.21. My containers in LXC are all going to be Ubuntu 24.04.
The problem is that when I create a container with Multipass, and then reboot that container, sometimes the container comes up with a new IP address and Multipass doesn't get the information about it. So for example, if I run multipass list, I'll get something like:
Name                    State             IPv4             Image
AY3                     Running           10.228.202.50    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

But if I run lxc list, I'll get:
 NAME |  STATE  |          IPV4           |                      IPV6                      |      TYPE       | SNAPSHOTS |

| AY3  | RUNNING | 10.228.202.51 (enp5s0)  | fd42:1fe6:e074:956a:5054:ff:fecf:9ef0 (enp5s0) | VIRTUAL-MACHINE | 0         |

This is a pretty out of the box setup (I think). So far, that lxc ip address (which is always one more than what it was at launch?) has not changed again.
When I restart the instance from lxc [ lxc restart AY3 ] - I see that it initially comes up with IP 10.228.202.50 (eth0), and then after a while shows 10.228.202.51 (enp5s0)... which seems like it might be the problem, but I don't really know!
Any suggestions on what to try or how to further troubleshoot this? Ultimately, I'd prefer these to never change IPs since I also need some firewall port forwarding rules based on IP (but that is another topic)

This question seems similar to: How to bridge local LAN using Multipass. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I think my question is fairly distinct from that one, though it does have some similarities. The answer to their problem seems to be using LXD with Multipass, but my problem is with those two things talking to each other.

Multipass is useful for the automation aspects of what I'm doing, but going around it with LXD/LXC might be just as easy as trying to work out what is happening. The alternative that I'm leaning towards at the moment is running a script at initiation of the container to make its initial IP its static IP.

Inside the container. I think I have my problem resolved - talking it out always helps. I've got an ansible script that disables cloud-init and creates an additional network file in /etc/netplan with the original IP address then applies that. I'll add that as an Answer below. Thanks!

Not exactly an answer to why the IP address is changing, but a workaround that resolves my immediate problem: using the ansible script that I'm using to generate the containers, I'm setting a static IP address inside the container to whatever the existing IP address is. This keeps Multipass and LXC in line. Here's the relative portion of the ansible playbook (probably inelegant as hell, but it works):

  - name: disable cloud-init
    copy:
      dest: "/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-cloud-init.cfg"
      content: |
        #disabling cloud-init
        network: {config: disabled}

  - name: create static ip file
    copy:
      dest: "/etc/netplan/60-static.yaml"
      content: |
        network:
          version: 2
          renderer: networkd
          ethernets:
            enp5s0:
              addresses:
                 
  - name: add current ip address
    shell: echo "        - $(ip address show enp5s0 | grep 'inet ' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | awk '{ print $2}')" >> /etc/netplan/60-static.yaml

  - name: set ip file permission
    shell: chmod 600 /etc/netplan/60-static.yaml

  - name: Apply static IP change
    shell: netplan apply

